# Can we implement a mobile version of the Stack Exchange homepage?

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, stackexchange.com

The Stack Exchange sites all have mobile versions (see Stack Overflow, Android Enthusiasts, Super User, etc.)

The [main Stack Exchange homepage](http://stackexchange.com) doesn't seem to have a mobile version, nor do any of the other pages at the root Stack Exchange domain such as [Leagues (a.k.a Top Users)](https://stackexchange.com/leagues) and [Privacy Policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy).

I have two queries:

- Do these pages have a mobile version that I'm not seeing for some reason?
- If not, can we implement a mobile version of these?

Implementing a mobile version of these pages would be useful for the following reasons (thanks to Journeyman Geek for some of these):

- It would allow users of platforms without the official Stack Exchange application (e.g. Windows Phone) or users experiencing issues with the app to use Stack Exchange on their mobile.
- Would fit neatly into the system. Every Stack Exchange website has partial mobile support (a few pages like 'Review' don't). Why leave the homepage out?
- Would be useful for users with devices with lower-DPI screens.

Comment: One question: why? I don't see in your question why this is a good idea. I like to have it and hence I upvoted, but it would be nice if you could include your reasons in your post.

Comment: Some possible uses - platforms without an official SE app, and lower dpi/size screens. I tend to use mobile SE chat on my netbook, or as a poor man's sidebar

Comment: Thanks both for the comments. I'll add reasons later when I have a proper keyboard

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I've added a few reasons. Don't quite understand why it would be useful for devices with lower-DPI screens but certainly understand why for platforms without the SE app. Please suggest more reasons if you can think of them, everyone!

Comment: A phone *is* a small, low dpi device.Chat mobile view works better on netbook and scales to smaller windows better - I sometimes switch to mobile view and create a small, narrow window to keep an eye on chat. I'd expect some of the same advantages

Comment: @Journeyman Geek - Thanks, yes. I understand this now